# ggplot does not work in function, passing in variable names as strings

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, parameter-passing, variable-names

I have following simple function but its ggplot command does not work. The command works all right when given from command line:

```
> testfn <- function(gdf, first, second){          
   library(ggplot2) 
   print(ggplot(gdf, aes(first, second)) + geom_point()) 
}                                                                                              
>
> testfn(mydataf, vnum1, vnum2)   
    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'second' not found
> 
> ggplot(mydataf, aes(vnum1, vnum2)) + geom_point()

>  (plots graph without any error)
```

I tried to use `aes_string` instead of `aes`; and also using `x=first, y=second`.  Things improve and one point is plotted! X and Y axes show numbers related to that point as the label. Only the first row is being plotted. Where is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us `dim(gdf)`. How many points do you think your x,y-series have? Also show us `dput(gdf)`, or at least truncate out a snippet of the x,y-series of say length 10.

Comment: Ah. On the command-line, `ggplot(gdf, aes(first, second))` would work fine. But inside your function, you're also passing in `first,second` as string variables. So yes you would need `aes_string(first,second)` inside your function testfn, since you're now passing variable names indirectly, through the string-variables `first,second`.

Comment: I strongly recommend you get your `ggplot()` command working on the command-line, before you then try to wrap it inside a function. Make your debugging life easy. Don't try to solve five problems at once.

Comment: Putting quotes around variable names while calling the function, i.e. testfn(mydataf, "vnum1", "vnum2" , works well. Earlier I was trying testfn(mydataf, vnum1, vnum2) which did not work. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I posted my above suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(As per my initial suggestion and your confirmation)

It was about how you were trying to pass string arguments of variable names into your fn.

- on the command-line, `ggplot(gdf, aes(first, second))` would work fine
- but inside your function, you're also passing in first,second as string variables. So yes you would now need `aes_string(first,second)` inside your function testfn, since you're now passing variable names indirectly, through the string-variables first,second.
- also since the variable-names `first,second` are strings, yes you do need to quote them when you call the fn. (I'm not sure what language mechanism ggplot's `aes()` uses to not need strings, but whatever. Use quotes.)
- see also the `quote()` command in R

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added the dput output and other details above.

Answer (score 4):

So the `aes_string` version works fine for me.

```
# set-up and sample data
library(ggplot2) 
set.seed(1)
mydataf <- data.frame(vnum1=rnorm(10), 
                      vnum2=rnorm(10))
# aes_string version called with characters
testfn <- function(gdf, first, second){            
  print(ggplot(gdf, aes_string(x=first, y=second)) + geom_point()) 
}                                                                                              
# aes_string version called with variables
testfn2 <- function(gdf, first, second){  
  print(ggplot(gdf, aes_string(x=deparse(substitute(first)), 
                               y=deparse(substitute(second)))) + 
          geom_point())
}     
# 3 times the same plot
ggplot(mydataf, aes(vnum1, vnum2)) + geom_point()
testfn(mydataf, "vnum1", "vnum2")   
testfn2(mydataf, vnum1, vnum2)
```

Comment: The command  testfn(mydataf, "vnum1", "vnum2") works all right. I was not quoting the names of variable. Thanks.